# How to print QrCode using Epson TM-T20 printer?

Tags: printing, qr-code, epson

I´m trying to use EPSON TM-T20 to print Qr Code using ESC POS commands

I can print simple text, expanded, cut paper, but when I tried to print Qr Code....not success

I´m using Linux and my printer is at /dev/usb/lp1.

I believe the ESC POS commands it´s ok, because there is another printer ( TANCA TP650) that use the same commands to print Qr Code, and this another printer is ok.

This is my code in Qt C++

```
    vetor.append(0x1D);// GS ( k pL pH cn fn n1 n2 (cn=49, fn=65)
    vetor.append(0x28);
    vetor.append(0x6B);
    vetor.append(0x04);
    vetor.append('\0');
    vetor.append(0x31);//cn=49
    vetor.append(0x41);//fn=65
    vetor.append(50);//n1 48..49 ou 49..50 ????
    vetor.append('\0');//n2

    //f67 := #29+#40+#107+#03+#00+#49+#67 + Chr(tamanho mod 17);
    vetor.append(0x1D);// GS ( k pL pH cn fn n (cn=49, fn=67)
    vetor.append(0x28);
    vetor.append(0x6B);
    vetor.append(0x03);
    vetor.append('\0');
    vetor.append(0x31);//cn
    vetor.append(0x43);//fn=67
    vetor.append(3);  //tamanho 1..16

    //f69 := #29+#40+#107+#03+#00+#49+#69+#03;
    vetor.append(0x1D);//GS ( k pL pH cn fn n (cn=49, fn=69)
    vetor.append(0x28);
    vetor.append(0x6B);
    vetor.append(0x03);
    vetor.append('\0');
    vetor.append(49);//cn
    vetor.append(69);//fn
    vetor.append(48);// error correction level 48..51 ????

    len+=3;
    qDebug() << "qrcode epson " << len << str;
    qDebug() << (len & 0xFF) << ((len & 0xFF00) >> 8);

    //f80 := #29+#40+#107 + AnsiChar(l mod 256) + AnsiChar(l div 256) + #49+#80+#48;
    vetor.append(0x1D);//GS ( k pL pH cn fn m d1...dk (cn=49, fn=80)
    vetor.append(0x28);
    vetor.append(0x6B);
    vetor.append(len & 0xFF);
    vetor.append((len & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    vetor.append(0x31);//cn
    vetor.append(0x50);//fn
    vetor.append(0x30);//m
    vetor.append(str);

    //f81 := #29+#40+#107+#03+#00+#49+#81+#48;
    vetor.append(0x1D);//GS ( k pL pH cn fn m (cn=49, fn=81)
    vetor.append(0x28);
    vetor.append(0x6B);
    vetor.append(0x03);
    vetor.append('\0');
    vetor.append(49);//cn
    vetor.append(81);//fn
    vetor.append(48);//m
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usualy print this receipt using serial line. But /dev/usb/lp1 is not a serial printer.
My code to print was:

fprintf(printer, pedidoprt);  //pedidoprt is a byte array of qrcode

And the C compiler understand \0 like end of string!!!!

I change my code to:

FILE *printer = fopen(caminho.toUtf8(), "w");

fwrite ( pedidoprt, sizeof(char), pedidoprt.size(), printer);

fclose(printer);

This point is closed!